# how to create model based Acl

Tags: zend-framework, model, zend-acl

if we have some modules in our application 
how we could create Model based ACL by zend framework for each models?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This topic is well described in the [Zend Framework 1.8 Web application development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194222), a book by Keith Pope.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the 3 posts at http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/

It's a good starting point to allow you to dynamically create ACL's based on models and per user permissions.